# codeigniter 2.0 inserting records in two tables at once

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm not sure how to handle this with active records or using manual sql. What I want to do is to add a record into the 'contact' table which has an auto incremented id, and then add a record into the "order" table with the id of the corresponding 'contact' record id.

I know I can get the id of the inserted contact record using $this->db->insert_id(), but does that only work when using active records?

Also, can I achieve this type of insert in one query, or must I split it up in two?

Comment: Which type of database are you using? You may be able to create a stored procedure that does the multiple steps with a single call to the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->db` does not refer to Active Record. You must choose to use Active Record, `$this->db` simply refers to the database abstraction layer.

That said, you can use `$this->db->insert_id()` immediately after a query (Active Record or not) to get its insert ID.

But to handle inserting multiple records at once that are dependent on eachother's IDs, I would switch to InnoDB as your table type (if you haven't already) and use CodeIgniter's [transactions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html).

Here's an example, adapted from CodeIgniter's documentation:

```
$this->db->trans_start();

$this->db->query('INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(id,field1,field2)');
$table1_id = $this->db->insert_id();

$this->db->query('INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(id,' . $table1_id . ',field2,field3)');

$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Codeigniter, the `$this->db` is named "Active Record" [sic!] so you already answered your own question in these terms. Otherwise you need to actually specify which kind of thing you mean by writing *"Active Record"*.

In PHP the Mysqli extension offers to run multiple queries at once: [`mysqli::multi_query`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php).

The last insert ID function exists in Mysql itself as well and can be used inside any SQL query then, it is called [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`<sup>*Mysql Docs*</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

```
INSERT INTO contact;
INSERT INTO order SET contact_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Maybe this is the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Additional Info

**Don't forget to Check For success of Transaction:**

```
$this->db->trans_complete();

    if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){// Check Transaction Result successful                          
         echo "<br>------- INFO WAS >>>>>>> NOT INSERTED <<<<<<< -------<br>";
    }else{
         echo "<br>------- >>>>>>> TRANSACTION SUCCESSFUL <<<<<<< -------<br>";
    }
```